# How to implement SiteCatalyst inbuilt variable 'pageType' in DTM?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I am trying to implement SiteCatalyst's inbuilt variable 's.pageType' using DTM (which we use to capture the 404 error pages).

I can definitely write this piece of code in DTM's s.code:
`s.pageType="errorPage"`

But the problem is the condition which would identify if the page is 404 error page or not, can be identified only at page code level (as per developers, there are exceptions which is thrown if error page comes up, which can be used to identify this condition on the page), but this logic we cannot be used in DTM. Along with this, on the 404 error page, the pageName variable should not be populated.
How this can be done, since I am fetching pageName from a data element in DTM (inside "Pageviews & Content" section) which would always fire on every page.

How to implement this, please help me out. Am I missing something ?

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 4):

It *sounds* like your setup is like this:

```
<dtm header tag>

// code that identifies 404 page

<dtm footer tag>
```

And it *sounds* like the issue is that since data elements are the first thing evaluated up in DTM top tag, your page name data element is being evaluated before it is known that it is a 404 page.

What I would do is in the code that identifies that it is a 404 page, make it output a global js var that flags the page as a 404 page, e.g. `window.is404Page=true;`.

From here, the overall goal now is to keep your existing data element and `pageName` assignment as-is, but then later override it with an empty string (and pop `pageType` instead).  You didn't really give any details about where you are actually setting `pageName`, so here are some scenarios that should point you in the right direction:

**Scenario 1: pageName is set in Pageviews & Content in the main tool config**

**1.a:** In **Library Management**, if you have set AA to load at **Page Bottom**, then go to **Customize Page Code** section, make sure it's set to execute "after UI Sttings" (*If you are already using this code box and it must be set to execute before UI settings, then skip this and go to **1.b***).  Click on Open Editor and add the following:

```
if (window.is404Page) {
  s.pageName='';
  s.pageType='errorPage';
}
```

**1.b:** In **Library Management**, if you have set AA to load at **Page Top**, then you will need to create a page load rule (or use an existing rule that will trigger on every page view) that evaluates at page bottom, on dom ready, or onload (basically anything but top of page - point here is to get it to eval *after* `is404Page` has been set). Within the rule, go to **Adobe Analytics > Custom Page Code** and add the code from **1.a** there.

**Scenario 2: pageName is set within a page load rule**

If your page load rule is set to trigger at "Top of Page" then you will need to create a separate rule that triggers after that. See **1.b.**

**2.a:** If you are setting `pageName` from within the DTM field using %dataElement% syntax, then add the code from **1.a** to the **Custom Page Code** section.

**2.b:** If you are setting `pageName` from within the **Custom Page Code** section, using e.g. `s.pageName=_satellite.getVar('dataElement');` then simply add the code from **1.a** directly below it.

**TL;DR:** set a global js var to act as a flag in your on-page code that determines if 404 page and then look for that in your DTM code to overwrite `pageName` and write `pageType` in DTM custom code sections that get eval'd *after* the js flag var is set.

Comment: Simply awesome Crayon. I am a big fan of your detailed replies :)
Mine is scenario 1 & I will follow what you just mentioned. Thank you so much !!